# Alinhamento html e css

Tags: html, css

Estou enfrentando algumas dificuldades ao tentar alinhar o seguinte conteúdo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo-para-header">
        <h2>Logo teste</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrap">
        <div class="modal wrap-user">
            <img src="">
            <span>TESTE</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="menu-aside">
    <ul>
        <li onclick="abreInicio()">
            Início
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li onclick="abreBanners()">
            Banner
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li onclick="abreProdutos()">
            Produtos
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="footer-menu-admin">
        Desenvolvido por Endrews.
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content-wrap">
    <div id="inicio-modal" class="modal">
        <div class="inicio">
            <div class="form-header">
                <p>Informações básicas</p>
            </div> ...
```

CSS

```
.content-wrap{
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(241,242,247,1);
    height: auto;
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
    overflow-y: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.wrap-user{
    background-color: red;
}
.modal{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1024px;
}
.inicio{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.header{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
.logo-para-header{
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 300px;
    height: 80px;
    padding-top: 23.889px;
    padding-bottom: 23.889px;
    padding-left: 55px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: rgba(31,181,173,1);
}
.menu-aside{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 300px;
    /* Altura mínima de 100% do espaço que sobra, evitando 'overflow' */
    min-height: 100%;
    /* Height auto ajustável pelo navegador */
    height: auto; 
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    color: rgba(174,178,183,1);
    background-color: rgba(50,50,58,1);
}
```

Comment: Quais são estas dificuldades? o que você esta tentando fazer? já usou algum sistema de grid ou media queries?

Comment: alinhar o 'teste' à informações básicas, usei sim, e é com ele mesmo que ta dando esse problema, e tentei também media queries, mas a margem e as posições não funcionam

Comment: Bacana, cria um fiddle com o exemplo completo usando as grids e tal que facilita na solução do problema

Comment: vai levar muito tempo :/ ta no serv da empresa e só volto segunda, eu queria um ex. funcional pra eu ja ir testando em casa :3

Comment: Também penso assim, o problema é que sem fornecer as informações básicas para testar e ver o problema fica difícil ajudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bastou alterar o `display` do `.header` para `block`.